# Problema com imprimir do Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Eu tenho uma estrutura de um sistema basicamente assim:

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a style="border-color: transparent;"
        data-toggle="tab" onclick="alterarAba(1)" href="#tabs-1"
        class="aba"><bean:message key="titulo.aba.principal"/></a></li>
    <li><a style="margin: 0px 10px; border-color: transparent;"
        data-toggle="tab" onclick="alterarAba(2)" href="#tabs-2"
        class="aba estatistica"><bean:message key="titulo.aba.estatistica"/></a></li>
</ul>


<div class="pagina">

    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-pane active">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tbody>
                <%@ include file="enderecoPaginaJSP.jsp"%>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-pane">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tbody>
                <%@ include file="enderecoPaginaJSP2.jsp"%>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estou com um problema que ao mandar imprimir a pagina do meu sistema no firefox, como a table de id="tabs-1" não "cabe" em uma única pagina o firefox, ao invés do firefox quebrar a pagina em duas ou mais, ele simplesmente "some" com o restante da pagina.
Eu já tentei utilizar o style `overflow:visible` na table só que não obtive sucesso.
Existe alguma forma de resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Talvez a resposta vai depender do conteudo de `<%@ include file="enderecoPaginaJSP2.jsp"%>`, eu acho, poderia fornecer um exemplo no jsfiddle ou no StackSnippet usando apenas HTML e CSS (sem o JSP)?